# How to colorize a specific contour with `ListContourPlot`

Tags: plotting

I have a list of data [as `.dat` file in my dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c8gzl8nmwvhct7t/paraloop_8.dat?dl=0).

And I have plot with `ListContourPlot` by this way:

```
j132 = Import["paraloop_8.dat"];
lista131 = 
  Table[{j132[[i, 1]], j132[[i, 2]], j132[[i, 8]]}, {i, 1, 
    Length[j132]}];

newStyle[x_] := x /. l_Line :> Sequence[Opacity[1], Thick, Red, l]

ListContourPlot[lista131, Contours -> 50, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameStyle -> FontSize -> 14, ImageSize -> 350] /. 
 Tooltip[x_, 0] :> Tooltip[newStyle[x], 0]
```

This way I can color with red the contour with value equal zero, but, 
if I want colorize the contour with another value, for exemple, `0.018`
I can't. 
What can be wrong?

Comment: `0.018` is not one of the 50  automatically generated contour lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `MeshFunctions`, `Mesh` and `MeshStyle`:

```
mesh ={ 0.18};
ListContourPlot[j132[[All, {1, 2, 8}]], Contours -> 50, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, FrameStyle -> FontSize -> 14, 
 ImageSize -> 350, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {mesh}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1, Red], Thick]]
```

[image]

**Note:** An alternative and simpler way to get your `lista131` is to use `132[[All, {1, 2, 8}]]`:

```
lista131 == j132[[All, {1, 2, 8}]]
```

> True

With a smaller (`Downsample`d) version of input data

```
mesh = {0.018, {.2, Directive[Dashed, Thick, Purple]}};
j132small = Downsample[j132[[All, {1, 2, 8}]], {20, 1}]
ListContourPlot[j132small, Contours -> 50, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 FrameStyle -> FontSize -> 14, ImageSize -> 350, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {mesh}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1, Red], Thick]]
```

[image]